# QT Iterate all children and get the text of that widget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a requirement to pack the content of all the child widgets of a QWidget. But since the children are of differnt types (QComboBox, QTextEdit, QSpinBox etc), it is  possible to write a generic function.

Current method I found was to either iterate each type and PackXML or while iterating identify type and do different getText functions.

eg:

```
QList<QWidget*> lstChildren = findChildren<QWidget*>();
foreach(QWidget* pWidget, lstChildren) {
     PackXML(pWidget->text());
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Since there is no generic 'getText()' method in QWidget or any class up the hierarchy, what would the most suitable way to iterate all children and get the text values of each widget.

Comment: None of those classes have getText(), and QComboBox does not even have "text()", just "currentText()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast

> QWidget * qobject_cast ( QObject * object ) Returns the given object
>   cast to type T if the object is of type T (or of a subclass);
>   otherwise returns 0. If object is 0 then it will also return 0. The
>   class T must inherit (directly or indirectly) QObject and be declared
>   with the Q_OBJECT macro. A class is considered to inherit itself.
>   Example:
>
> QObject *obj = new QTimer;          // QTimer inherits
>   QObject
>
> QTimer *timer = qobject_cast(obj);  // timer == (QObject
>   *)obj
>
> QAbstractButton *button = qobject_cast(obj);
>    // button == 0
>
> The qobject_cast() function behaves similarly to the
>   standard C++ dynamic_cast(), with the advantages that it doesn't
>   require RTTI support and it works across dynamic library boundaries.
>   qobject_cast() can also be used in conjunction with interfaces; see
>   the Plug & Paint example for details. Warning: If T isn't declared
>   with the Q_OBJECT macro, this function's return value is undefined.
>   See also QObject::inherits().

Comment: Got it working as suggested, thanks. But not entirely satisfied with the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general `text` property for all widgets, so using polymorphism from `QWidget` down won't work.  However you can get some way there by querying the existence of a `text` property and using that if it has one, otherwise you will have to cast to it's real type and call the appropriate getter method (assuming there is one).